# java printing outside of a loop

Tags: java

I'm a high school student learning to program, and I can't get around this problem right now. I'm trying to print the averages outside of the loop, but I don't know how.

```
for (int index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++) {
    double tempSum = 0;
    tempSum += temperature[index];
    double averageTemp = tempSum / temperature.length;
    double rainSum = 0;
    rainSum += precipitation[index];

}

//Output: display table of weather data including average and total
System.out.println();
System.out.println("           Weather Data");
System.out.println("      Location: " + city + ", " + state);
System.out.println("Month     Temperature (" + tempLabel + ")     Precipitation (" + precipLabel + ")");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("***************************************************");

for (int index = 0; index < precipitation.length; index++) {
    System.out.println(month[index] + "     " + temperature[index] + "     " + precipitation[index]);
}

System.out.println("Average Temperature: " + averageTemp + "    Total Rainfall: " + rainSum);
```

Comment: You need to declare the variables outside the loop. Before the loop to be precise.

Comment: you need to declare tempSum outside the for loop, and also calculate          averageTemp ouside the loop

Comment: you doing **worse things** in for loop the **rainsum** will never go beyond 0 define variables outside loop

Comment: to solve any problem, you need to understand, what needs to be done. Then code step by step. I'm pretty sure, before posting your question, you have never reviewed your code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The comments provide the right idea. Variables in Java have block scope, which means that they are unavailable outside the block in which they are declared. JavaScript has "hoisting," which means that, no matter where the var keyword is used, the variable will be defined.

Move your variable declarations outside of the "for" blocks. Then they will be available when the loop is done. You can also do that for the "index" variable if you need to know the its last value. Typically, that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the variable `averageTemp` is only existing/ accessible within the `for`-loop.
To have it accessible outside of the loop, you need to the declare outside, in your case before the loop. Kind of

```
double averageTemperature;
for (....) {
```

In the `for`-loop you could sum up the temperatures to `tempSum` and *after* the loop is finished divide `tempSum`by the number of items you iterated over in the loop. If you would like to do so, keep in mind that also `tempSum` has to be declared before entering the loop.